# azure gpt api stream response

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, openai-api

I want to stream responce from gpt api in node.js. I can stream response from OpenAI GPT api using this code:

```
import OpenAI from "openai";

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: 'my_api_key',
});
    
const response = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages: [
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Generate Lorem Ipsum text."
        }
    ],
    temperature: 0,
    stream: true
});


for await (const chunk of response[Symbol.asyncIterator]()) {
    try {
        process.stdout.write(chunk['choices'][0]['delta']['content']);
    } catch (err) {
    }
}
```

How can I rewrite this code using azure? I tried something like this, but does not work:

```
const {OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential} = require("@azure/openai");
const endpoint = 'my_endpoint';
const azureApiKey = 'my_azure_gpt_api_key';


const messages = [
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Generate Lorem Ipsum text."
    }
];


async function main() {
    const client = new OpenAIClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(azureApiKey));
    const deploymentId = "gpt35-turbo-deploy";
    const response = await client.getChatCompletions(deploymentId, messages, {
        temperature: 0,
        stream: true
    })

    // TODO console.log(response['choices'][0]['message']['content']) how?
}

main().catch((err) => {
    console.error("The sample encountered an error:", err);
});

module.exports = {main};
```

Should I use library mentioned above? Or can I use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Azure OpenAI SDK does not support streaming responses directly at the moment.

You can implement a stream chat completions as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/openai-javascript-beta/) with [readableStream.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/openai/openai/samples/v1-beta/javascript/readableStream.js) sample which use `listChatCompletions` with `maxTokens` value.

Below is a sample code snippet:

```js
const { OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/openai");

require("dotenv").config();

const endpoint = process.env["ENDPOINT"] || "<endpoint>";
const azureApiKey = process.env["AZURE_API_KEY"] || "<api key>";

const messages = [
  { role: "system", content: "You are a helpful assistant. " },
  { role: "user", content: "Can you help me?" },
  
  { role: "user", content: "Generate Lorem Ipsum text." },
];

async function main() {
  console.log("== Streaming Chat Completions Sample ==");

  const client = new OpenAIClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(azureApiKey));
  const deploymentId = "<Deployment Name>";
  const events =  await client.listChatCompletions(deploymentId, messages, { maxTokens: 128 });
  const stream = new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      for await (const event of events) {
        controller.enqueue(event);
      }
      controller.close();
    },
  });
 
  const reader = stream.getReader();
  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await reader.read();
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    for (const choice of value.choices) {
      if (choice.delta?.content !== undefined) {
        console.log(choice.delta?.content);
      }
    }
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("The sample encountered an error:", err);
});
module.exports = { main };
```

[image]

**Note:** This is sample output, and you can modify and re-configure according to your need.

Comment: Yes, it can be solved using listChatCompletions. Thx

Comment: Interesting, I don't see any function called `listChatCompletions` in this library, how/where did you find it? It's not mentionened in any of the documentation, and its not in the source code on npm. When I try to call it i get: ` client.listChatCompletions is not a function` Could you share a link to where you found it? 